# SQL QUERY using between min and max

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have recruiter table with columns `jobname,minexp,maxexp,minsalary,maxsalary`

When I get the input from the user at  runtime for experience(for example 4),I need to fetch the records where experience between `minexp` and `maxexp`.

Comment: How are you going to fetch the data between if you have one value for experience between 4 and what ?? And which experience between minexp or maxexp ?? And some sample data and expected output.

Comment: There is no column called `EXPERIENCE` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL BETWEEN Operator for this

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM recruiter
WHERE Experience BETWEEN minexp AND maxexp;
```

Comment: And where do you see the column `EXPERIENCE` in the question description? There are only two columns as OP said, `minexp,maxexp`

Comment: Yes bro... :)
But he has said "When I get the input from the user at runtime for `experience`; I need to fetch the records where experience between `minexp` and `maxexp`". So I assumed there is another column in input for `Experience`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM recruiter
WHERE &user_input BETWEEN minexp AND maxexp;